# Eclipse - clicking inside the console changes colors

Tags: eclipse, ide, pydev, eclipse-cdt

I am using

```
Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
Build id: 20150219-0600
```

and I have a dark theme plug in. U use pydev for python development. I changed the colors for the console, but whenever I click inside it, they revert to defaults. I don't know if this is related, but I only started seeing this recently, after installing CDT.

Also, the color changes after the execution of the program finishes, i.e. when it is in running state it is one color, and then when it's over, another.

Comment: check if there isn't option like 'color when focused', maybe it is normal behaviour and you need just change more values

Comment: Where would I check this option?